# How to aggregate data returned by 2 Promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 2 promises being imported in a js file.
employees, managers
Both these promises contains data as Array of Json objects.
e.g.

```
employees = [ {"id": 1, "name": "Andrew", "age": 22}, {"id": 2, "name": "Eric", "age": 34}] 
managers = [ {"id": 1, "name": "Andrew", "department": "logistics"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Eric", "department": "sales"}]
```

I want to merge these data sets based on id and return single array of Json objects like below-

```
empManager = [ {"id": 1, "name": "Andrew", "age" : 22, "department": "logistics"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Eric", "age": 34, "department": "sales"}]
```

I am trying something like below using Promise chaining but it is not working

```
import {employees, managers} from './model';

export let empManager = function getData() {
    let employees;
    employees().then(emps => {
        employees = emps;
        return managers;
    }).then(mgrs => {
        return employees.map( e=> Object.assign(e, mgrs.find(m => m.id == e.id)))
    })
}
```

Further when I am trying to fetch the value from empManager as below, it is giving error.

```
console.log(empManager())  // error - "mgrs.find is not a function".
```

How should I achieve this aggregation on result from 2 promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first resolve both promises using `Promise.all`.

```
// Mimic async call.
employees = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve([ {"id": 1, "name": "Andrew", "age": 22}, {"id": 2, "name": "Eric", "age": 34}]));
managers = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve([ {"id": 1, "name": "Andrew", "department": "logistics"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Eric", "department": "sales"}]));

// Wrap in async anonymous function to be able to use await.
(async () => {

  // Use Promise.all to wait for both calls
  const [emps, mgrs] = await Promise.all([
    employees(),
    managers()
  ]);

  // Merge epmloyees
  const merged = {};
  emps
    .concat(mgrs)
    .forEach(u => {
      if(!(u.id in merged)) {
        merged[u.id] = {};
      }
      for(const key in u) {
        merged[u.id][key] = u[key];
      }
    })
  ;

  // Convert merged object into array again.
  console.log(Object.values(merged));

})();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Erik! Resolving the Promises using async and await worked!
For merging the data I did as below. mergedData below is again a Promise which contains merged data from both Promises.
export const mergedData = emps.map(e => Object.assign(e, mgrs.find(m => m.UserId == e.UserId)));

Comment: `async/await` taints your whole algorithm with asynchronism and couples it with the data when only the data retrieval was async at the beginning. `emps` and `mgrs` should be arguments to a function you call within a `then` IMO. The function would be just a readable, but also reusable.

Comment: @geoffrey you are probably right. However I do not care to much for this example since the answer to the question comes down to using `Promise.all`.

Comment: Sure. I had to address it for other readers. The obsession of accessing values directly with `await` makes the surface area of async code grow and postpones the problem instead of solving it.

Comment: @geoffrey true, thnx for your addition.